# in wpf, how can I use a standard dialog to select a directory

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I need the user to select a directory, not a file.  How can I use Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog (or any other component) to do that?

I'm using WPF4.0 in VisualStudio 2010 (.net 4.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog :

```
var dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true; //if you want new folders as well
dlg.SelectedPath = someStartPath; //where to start
if( dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
{
  //ok user selected something
  DoStuffWith( dlg.SelectedPath );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have access to that, and many other standard dialogs and controls from the Win32 ecosystem through the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).